# mySQL JOIN three tables - Ecommerce items , views and sales

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, e-commerce

I am building an Ecommerce system using php mySql, and I don't know how to LEFT JOIN three tables.

I need a list from all store items adding how many views and sales each item has

```
            TABLE #1 - store_sales
            ---------------
            itemID | date
            --------------

            TABLE #2 - store_views
            --------------
            itemID | date
            --------------

            TABLE #3 - store_items 
            ---------------------------------
            itemID | itemName 
            ---------------------------------

            RESULT
            -----------------------
            itemID | itemName | COUNT(store_sales) | COUNT(store_views)


            EXAMPLE:
            -----------------------
            itemID | itemName | COUNT(store_sales) | COUNT(store_views) 
            1         PHONE             3                   45 
            2         BOOK              5                   61
```

### MY CODE WITH ERROR:

```
            SELECT
            a.itemID    ,
            b.itemID    ,
            c.itemID    ,
            COUNT(if(a.itemID   = c.itemID  , a.itemID  , NULL)) AS views       ,
            COUNT(if(b.itemID   = c.itemID  , b.itemID  , NULL)) AS sales               

            FROM store_views a

            LEFT JOIN store_sales b
            ON a.itemID = b.itemID 

            LEFT JOIN store_items c
            ON a.itemID = c.itemID

            WHERE 1=1
            GROUP BY itemID
```

Comment: Don't you have any primary key for store_sales and store_views ?

Comment: no, each time someone visit a store item it creates a new record using the item id and the timedate stamp. The same goes for store_sales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get count for sales and views separately in sub selects and then do a left join with your item table, Used COALESCE to skip null records for count

```
SELECT
a.itemID ,
COALESCE(b.item_sales,0),
COALESCE(c.item_views,0)
FROM  store_items a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT itemID,COUNT(*) as item_sales
    FROM store_sales
    GROUP BY itemID  
) b ON a.itemID = b.itemID 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT itemID,COUNT(*) as item_views
    FROM store_views v
    GROUP BY itemID
) c ON a.itemID = c.itemID
```